# iPhone XML Parser - [c setImage:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"img"]]; WARNING

Tags: iphone, xml, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiimageview, ios-simulator

Hi I am having issues with the following and it crashes the iPhone simulator, while the script has no errors it did bring up one warning in this script.

```
[c setImage:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"img"]];
```

The warning is

> City may not respond to -setImage:

I am not sure what I have done wrong here is the fill source code.

```
#import "LocationsParser.h"
@implementation LocationsParser
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
-(id) initWithContext: (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjContext
{
    self = [super init];
    [self setManagedObjectContext:managedObjContext];
    return self;
}
- (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSURL *)URL parseError:(NSError **)error
{
    // /Applications/MyExample.app/MyFile.xml
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL];
    // Set self as the delegate of the parser so that it will receive the parser delegate methods callbacks.
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    // Depending on the XML document you're parsing, you may want to enable these features of NSXMLParser.
    [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];

    NSError *parseError = [parser parserError];
    if (parseError && error) {
        *error = parseError;
    }

    [parser release];
}

-(void) emptyDataContext
{
    // Get all counties, It's the top level object and the reference cascade deletion downward
    NSMutableArray* mutableFetchResults = [CoreDataHelper getObjectsFromContext:@"County" :@"Name" :NO :managedObjectContext];

    // Delete all Counties
    for (int i = 0; i
```

Comment: This warning "City may not respond to -setImage:" want tell that your City object doesn't implement this method, so your issue must be there.

Comment: What type of object is c? Does it extend any native classes? Also your source code is incomplete/irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

**[c setImage:(id)[attributeDict objectForKey:@"img"]];**

Answer (score 0):

`c` - what is it? E.g., if it is supposed to be `UIImageView`, you can do so:

```
[(UIImageView *)c setImage:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"img"]];
```